# Составление массива из локальных переменных на СИ

Tags: c

Необходимо написать программу которая в результате выводит массив, составленный из значений локальных переменных. Причем некоторые значения массива должны быть представлены шестнадцатеричными (напр. "7f"), другие десятичными (вида "32" или "000635").

Как в таком случае лучше вытащить значения из функций void в массив, находящийся в функции main?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Command, Volume, Error; 
int array_of_variables [3] = {Command, Volume, Error};


void command_fuction ()

{

//обработка переменной Command// 


int Command = 31; //результат//
}


void volume_fuction ()

{

//обработка переменной Volume // 


int Volume = 045673; //результат//
}


void error_fuction ()

{

//обработка переменной Error // 


int Error = 02; //результат//
}


int main()

{
    
    command_fuction ();
    volume_fuction ();
    error_fuction ();



    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        printf("%d\t", array_of_variables[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **_некоторые значения массива должны быть представлены шестнадцатеричными (напр. "7f"), другие десятичными (вида "32" или "000635")._**  Это не шестнадцатеричные и десятичные, это строковые  величины. И массив у Вас должен быть массивом строк.  Либо каким-то образом определять формат при выводе на консоль.

Answer (score 0):

> Как в таком случае лучше вытащить значения из функций void в массив

Зачем Вам что-то **вытаскивать** ?! Массив *array_of_variables* у вас и так объявлен глобальным. Т.е. он в **общем** доступе:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array_of_variables [3];


void command_fuction ()
{
    int Command = 31; //результат//
    array_of_variables[0] = Command;
}


void volume_fuction ()
{
    int Volume = 045673; //результат//
    array_of_variables[1] = Volume;
}


void error_fuction ()
{
    int Error = 02; //результат//
    array_of_variables[2] = Error;
}


int main()
{
    
    command_fuction ();
    volume_fuction ();
    error_fuction ();

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        printf("%d\t", array_of_variables[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```